# Clarification of L in R

Tags: r, integer, numeric

My trail on `L` in R is:

```
c<-1:10
c
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
c[-1]
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
c[-2]
# [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
c[-1L]
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
c[-2L]
# [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I tried using `?L` without success.

What indeed is `x[<n>L]`? Any example for further usage of it?

Comment: You can read about `L` on p. 14 [**here**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf). "We can use the `L` suffix to qualify any number with the intent of making it an explicit integer". I thought I would find something about `L` on `?as.integer`, but no.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This answer is a summary of the comments above. It is basically just pointers to various help texts, but as evident from OP's attempt with `?L`, it is not always easy to find the relevant help text. I was expecting to find something about `L` in `?as.integer`, but no. Hopefully this answer is more useful than a pile of comments.

- In the [**R language
  definition**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Constants)
  you will find:   "We can use the `L` suffix to qualify any number
  with the intent of making it an explicit integer"
- From `?NumericConstants`:   "[...]  All other numeric constants start
  with a digit or period and are either a decimal or hexadecimal
  constant optionally followed by `L`"

  "An numeric constant immediately followed by `L` is regarded as an
  integer number when possible (and with a warning if it contains a
  ".")."

  "You can combine the "`0x`" prefix with the "`L`" suffix".
- You may also find it useful to check the examples on floating point
  vs. integers in the section "Two Kinds Revisited"
  [**here**](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/impatient-r/more-r-key-objects/more-r-numbers/).
  "Put capital `L` (as in “long”) after a number to make R create it as
  an integer".
- Not specifically about `L`, but always relevant in the floating point
  vs. integers context is [**FAQ7.31**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f): "Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?".

---

**Threads with discussions about the efficiency of `L`:**

Threads on R-help where others have struggled to find documentation about `L`, with a possible explanation of why the letter `L`, and why `L` vs `as.integer` in terms of efficiency.

1. [**Difference between 10 and 10L**](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-May/311759.html)

First William Dunlap:

> Why not `10I` for integer?  Perhaps because "`I`" and "`l`" look too similar, perhaps because "`i`" and "`I`" sound too similar. The "`L`" does not mean "long": integers are 4 bytes long.

Then Brian Ripley:

> Actually it does: this notation dates from the C language on 16-bit
> computers where integers were 16-bits and longs were 32-bit (and R has
> no 'long' type).

> The author of this in R never explained why he chose the notation, but
> it is shorter than `as.integer(10)`, and **more efficient as the coercion is
> done at parse time**.

2. [**The L Word**](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-February/thread.html#269783)
   Discussion about the efficiency in different situations, with some benchmarkings.
3. [**R history: Why 'L; in suffix character ‘L’ for integer constants?**](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-June/074462.html)
4. More discussions [**here**](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/169928/focus=169933).

Comment: In the book [Efficient R Programming](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/7-1-data-types.html#vectors), Colin Gillespie says `L` is for *Literal*. No other reference is given though for this statement.