# Why would R use the "L" suffix to denote an integer?

Tags: r, parsing, integer, semantics

In R we all know it is convenient for those times we want to ensure we are dealing with an integer to specify it using the `"L"` suffix like this:

```
1L
# [1] 1
```

If we don't explicitly tell R we want an integer it will assume we meant to use a `numeric` data type...

```
str( 1 * 1 )
# num 1
str( 1L * 1L )
# int 1
```

Why is "L" the preferred suffix, why not "I" for instance? Is there a historical reason?

In addition, why does R allow me to do (with warnings):

```
str(1.0L)
# int 1
# Warning message:
# integer literal 1.0L contains unnecessary decimal point
```

But not..

```
str(1.1L)
# num 1.1
#Warning message:
#integer literal 1.1L contains decimal; using numeric value
```

I'd expect both to either return an error.

Comment: For the first part of your question ("Why is "L" used as a suffix"): in [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191324/clarification-of-l-in-r/22192378#22192378) I refer to [**a thread**](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/262888/focus=262902) where William Dunlop and Brian Ripley discuss "a possible explanation of why the letter `L`".

Comment: @Henrik thank for (both) the links. Your answer there is also nice and informative.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### Why is "L" used as a suffix?

I've never seen it written down, but I theorise in short for two reasons:

1. Because R handles complex numbers which may be specified using the
   suffix `"i"` and this would be too simillar to `"I"`
2. Because R's integers are 32-bit long integers and "L" therefore appears to be sensible shorthand for referring to this data type.

The value a long integer can take depends on the word size. R does not natively support integers with a word length of 64-bits. Integers in R have a word length of 32 bits and are signed and therefore have a range of  `−2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. Larger values are stored as `double`.

[This wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types) has more information on common data types, their conventional names and ranges.

And also from `?integer`

> Note that current implementations of R use 32-bit integers for integer vectors, so the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly.

---

#### Why do 1.0L and 1.1L return different types?

The reason that `1.0L` and `1.1L` will return different data types is because returning an integer for `1.1` will result in loss of information, whilst for `1.0` it will not (but you might want to know you no longer have a floating point numeric). Buried deep with the lexical analyser (`/src/main/gram.c:4463-4485`) is this code (part of the function `NumericValue()`) which actually creates a `int` data type from a `double` input that is suffixed by an ascii `"L"`:

```c
/* Make certain that things are okay. */
if(c == 'L') {
double a = R_atof(yytext);
int b = (int) a;
/* We are asked to create an integer via the L, so we check that the
   double and int values are the same. If not, this is a problem and we
   will not lose information and so use the numeric value.
*/
if(a != (double) b) {
    if(GenerateCode) {
    if(seendot == 1 && seenexp == 0)
        warning(_("integer literal %s contains decimal; using numeric value"), yytext);
    else {
        /* hide the L for the warning message */
        *(yyp-2) = '\0';
        warning(_("non-integer value %s qualified with L; using numeric value"), yytext);
        *(yyp-2) = (char)c;
    }
    }
    asNumeric = 1;
    seenexp = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: the [relevant section of the r language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Constants) doesn't seem to say anything more enlightening

Comment: I think in the new version of R integer size of 64 bit is supported.

Comment: @user1436187 I don't think so. I quoted from `R 3.1.0`. These would be `double` types as stated in the answer. See e.g. [**here**](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Reading-64-bit-integers-tp3414704p3416388.html). An integer use the C `int` type which is 32bits long. Integers are now also representable using double precision vectors using the `double` data type.

Answer (score 5):

Probably because R is written in C, and L is used for a (long) integer in C