# How to handle a Poisson distribution in R

Tags: r, loops, distribution, poisson

Consider the Poisson distribution `x1, x2, ... ~ pois(1)` with lambda=1.
I want to write a function that receives a number as input (consider it a) and gives us as output ***the smallest n*** (minimum n) which is true for `sum(xi)>=a, i=1:n`.
I think using a `while` loop could be fine for this situation (but I am not sure that it's the best way). Perhaps it can be done using other loops like `for` loop. I do not know how to handle this situation containing a Poisson distribution in R?

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop is simple enough to code. It accumulates the values of `rpois` in `s` for *sum* while `s < a`, counting the iterations in `n`.

```
minpois <- function(a){
  n <- 0L
  s <- 0L
  while(s < a) {
    n <- n + 1L
    s <- s + rpois(1L, lambda = 1)
  }
  n
}

set.seed(2020)
minpois(10)
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I have a question. Why have you used 0L and 1L? Why not 0 and 1? If we write n<-0, s<-0, n<-n+1 and s<-s+rpois(1,lambda=1) does it work? What is letter L in your code? @RuiBarradas

Comment: @vahid It works without the `L` but since the numbers are integers, I use it. See [the R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Constants) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350733/why-would-r-use-the-l-suffix-to-denote-an-integer).

Comment: What is 1L in rpois(1L, lambda = 1)? Why did you put this argument equal to 1L? How did you find it?

Comment: @vahid The loop generates 1 random variable at a time, see `help('rpois')`.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas. In your comment, when you said "It works without the L but since the numbers are integers", I have a question regarding "the numbers are integers". Does rpois(n,lambda) always generate integer values?

Comment: @vahid Yes, it does.